# get news list by category id .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0, repository-pattern

We have 3 models Category, Post and PostCategory. I want get news list by category id using generic repositor pattern so how to implement it.

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategories { get; set; }
    }
public class PostCategory
    {
          public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public int PostsId { get; set; }
        public Posts Posts { get; set; }
    }
public class Posts
    {
       
        public int Id { get; set; }
      
        public string Title { get; set; }
       
        public string Description { get; set; }
       
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public Published IsPublished { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PostCategory> PostCategories { get; set; }=new HashSet<PostCategory>();
    }
```

this is code which i try to get this

```
            var postList = _unitOfWork.GenericRepository<Posts>()
               .GetAll(include: y => y.Include(d => d.PostCategories).ThenInclude(e => e.Category)).ToList();`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
public List<Post> GetByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{
    var postRepository = _unitOfWork.GenericRepository<Posts>();
    var posts = postRepository
        .GetAll(include: x => x.Include(y => y.PostCategories))
        .Where(x => x.PostCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId))
        .ToList();

    return posts;
}
```

This is not the good code because you fetch the whole `Post` table from the database, and then filter them on the C# side. To apply your filter on the SQL side, you need to define your predicate before your `IQueryable` query becomes `IEnumerbale`. To do that with your generic repository, you need to have a `predicate` parameter in your `GetAll` method (maybe you have it, I don't know). The code will be something like that:

```
public List<Post> GetByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{
    var postRepository = _unitOfWork.GenericRepository<Posts>();
    var posts = postRepository
        .GetAll(
            include: x => x.Include(y => y.PostCategories),
            predicate: x => x.PostCategories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId))
        .ToList();

    return posts;
}
```

---

P.S.

With EF you can get rid of PostCategory class, and have many-to-many relationship just having navigation properties.

```
public class Category
{
    // other stuff
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    // other stuff
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

// code in OnModelCreating inside your DbContext
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Post>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Categories)
    .WithMany(c => c.Posts)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("PostCategories"));

// new implementation
public List<Post> GetByCategoryId(int categoryId)
{
    var postRepository = _unitOfWork.GenericRepository<Posts>();
    var posts = postRepository
        .GetAll(predicate: p => p.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == categoryId))
        .ToList();

    return posts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Dalival. I got what I want.